# How to generate "triangles" parameter of Mayavi triangular_mesh using triangles which are known vertices coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, mayavi

I have triangles which construct surface of sphere. I want to draw the surface using mayavi triangular_mesh function. The function has "triangles" parameter which is list of triplets (or an array) list the vertices in each triangle. I know vertices coordinate all of triangles. But I don't know how to generate this parameter.

I also tried to generate "triangles" parameter using matplotlib Triangulation function (`triangles = matplotlib.tri.Triangulation(longitudes, latitudes).triangles`). However, in some places of surface, the triangles are connected incorrectly (can be seen Figure 1).

[image: Incorrect connection of triangles]

Figure 1. Incorrect connection of triangles

How to generate "triangles" parameter of Mayavi triangular_mesh using triangles which are known vertices coordinates

**Data Format**

`x, y` and `z` are Cartesian coordinate of triangles. For example; `(x[0], y[0], z[0]), (x[1], y[1], z[1])` and `(x[2], y[2], z[2])` are vertices of a triangle. Next triangle has `(x[3], y[3], z[3]), (x[4], y[4], z[4])` and `(x[5], y[5], z[5])` vertices coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put it together using the indices.
Take a look at the shape of `triangles`.
It has three indices per triangle that is used 
on `x`, `y` and `z`.

```
import numpy as np
import mayavi.mlab as mlab

x = np.random.rand(30)
y = np.random.rand(30)
z = np.random.rand(30)
s = np.random.rand(30)

triangles = np.random.randint(0, 30, size=(10, 3))
print(triangles)

mlab.triangular_mesh(x, y, z, triangles, scalars=s)    
mlab.orientation_axes()
mlab.show()
```